# Solrj error adding doc

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm following the examples given on the wiki page to index a page via solrj. i've tried various ways to get this to work but somehow, i keep getting an error that looks like this:

**ERROR: [doc=1] multiple values encountered for non multiValued field id: [1, 34d47c153efcf221]**

My schema is pretty simple (just for test)

```
    <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="name" type="string_filename" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="size" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="created_at" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="updated_at" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

The code looks like this:

```
String solrHost = "localhost";
String coreName = "files";
SolrServer solr = null;
try {
    solr = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://"+solrHost+":8983/solr/"+coreName);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR:" + e.getMessage());
}

SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", 1);
doc.addField("name", "testfile.pdf");
doc.addField("size", 34234234);

try{
    `solr.add(doc);
}    catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR adding docs: " + e.getMessage());
}

try{
    solr.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("commit FAiled.");
}
```

Hopefully it's something really trivial that i'm missing. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please shoe the definition of your `string_filename` fieldType.

Comment: the string_filename fieldtype is one I concocted with the lucene ICU libraries to include utf8 strings.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to index 2 values for id, namely 1 and 34d47c153efcf221.

Comment: Not so, if you look at the code, I am doing a "doc.addField("id", 1)"

Comment: I think this might be a solrconfig issue. When I comment out "dedupe" in the update handler, indexing succeeds. But when I enable "dedupe", I get the weird funky error: multiple values encountered for non multiValued field id: [1, 34d47c153efcf221] .

Answer (score 0):

After much reading and experimenting. I found out what the issue was. In order to have dedupe enabled, I needed to add another field in the schema file.
so something like

```
<field name="signature" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="false" / >
```

Then in my solrconfig, I need to set this field "signature" in the "signatureField" element:

```
 <updateRequestProcessorChain name="dedupe">
   <processor class="solr.processor.SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <bool name="enabled">true</bool>
     <str name="signatureField">signature</str>
     <bool name="overwriteDupes">false</bool>
     <str name="fields">id,name</str>
     <str name="signatureClass">solr.processor.Lookup3Signature</str>
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed! :)